# passing arguments from php to python using shell_exec from browser

Tags: php, python, browser, crash, command

I have a simple php script that passes a couple variables to and runs a python script with the shell_exec command. When I run this php script from the shell it works just fine. However, when I run the php script from the browser, it causes the server to crash. I've tried this with both exec and shell_exec php functions. Why would it matter whether I run the script form the shell or the browser?

For the record, I can run other commands from the browser successfully, such as "tar -xcpvf path.tar.gz"

Here is the php script that has trouble from the browser:

```
    <?php
    $inputs = array(    
    'location' => "Los Angeles",
    'date' => '11/01/2012',
    );
    $cmd = 'python simple.py '.$inputs['location'].' '.$inputs['date'];
    $results = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $results;      
    ?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check your error log - what kind of error do you get ?

Answer (score 2):

Without the error log, I can't be certain, but it looks like you're not quoting your parameters. So the actual command you're passing into shell_exec is:

```
python simple.py Los Angeles 11/01/2012
```

What you're (presumably) wanting is this:

```
python simple.py "Los Angeles" "11/01/2012"
```

To get that, your $cmd line should look like this:

```
$cmd = 'python simple.py "'.$inputs['location'].'" "'.$inputs['date'].'"';
```